# Error in using atof() and strtod() when trying to convert numerical string into float

Tags: c, stack, type-conversion, postfix-notation

I've made code to read expressions from a file in postfix notation (RPN) and output the value. While it is correctly reading the values and displaying outputs for expressions without any numbers that use decimal places, it defaults to error for any expression containing a float value.

Basically, if a digit is found within a string read from file, it needs to be converted to a float.

I've unsuccesfully tried setting the data value equal to atof(str) and strtod(const char *str, char **endptr), but I'm still getting the error.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int top = -1;
float stack[500];

/* push the given data into the stack */
void push (int data) {
stack[++top] = data;
}

 /* Pop the top element from the stack */
float pop () {
float data;
if (top == -1)
    return -1;
data = stack[top];
stack[top] = 0;
top--;
return (data);
}

int main() {

char str[500];
FILE *p;
if((p=fopen("testfile1.txt","r"))==NULL){
    printf("\n Unable to open file string.txt");
    return 1;
}

while(fgets(str,500,p)!='\0'){

    float data = -1, operand1, operand2, result;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (isdigit(str[i])) {
            /*
             * if the i/p char is digit, parse
             * character by character to get
             * complete operand
             */
            data = (data == -1) ? 0 : data;
            data = (data * 10) + (str[i] - 48);
            continue;
        }

        if (data != -1) {
            /* if the i/p is operand, push it into the stack */
            push(data);
        }

        if (str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-'
                || str[i] == '*' || str[i] == '/') {
            /*
             * if the i/p is an operator, pop 2 elements
             * from the stack and apply the operator
             */
            operand2 = pop();
            operand1 = pop();
            if (operand1 == -1 || operand2 == -1)
                break;
            switch (str[i]) {
                case '+':
                    result = operand1 + operand2;
                    /* push the result into the stack */
                    push(result);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    result = operand1 - operand2;
                    push(result);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    result = operand1 * operand2;
                    push(result);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    result = operand1 / operand2;
                    push(result);
                    break;
            }
        }
        data = -1;
    }
    if (top == 0)
        printf("Output:%3.2f\n", stack[top]);
    else
        printf("have given wrong postfix expression\n");
    return 1;
}
}
```

There are 5 postfix expressions in the file, and they are as follows:

```
 13 1 - 2 / 3 155 + *
 100 100 100 100 + + +
 10.33 2 2 2 2 2 * * * * *
 30 10 - 10 - 10 - 2 *
 300 13.25 - 11 3 - / 4 5 - * 3 /
```

But, the output of the program denies the third expression because it contains 10.33, which is not an integer value.

Output:

```
Output: 948.00
Output: 400.00
have given wrong postfix expression
Output:   0.00
Output: 300.00
```

Does anyone know how to modify this code to handle floats?

Cheers.

Comment: regarding this line: `while(fgets(str,500,p)!='\0'){`,  the function: `fgets()` never returns a NUL character.  From the man page: `fgets() return s on success, and NULL on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.` where `s` is the pointer that was passed as the first parameter.  Suggest checking for `NULL` rather than `'\0'`

Comment: regarding this line: `if (isdigit(str[i])) {` this cannot input a float value, because a `.` is not a digit and without the `.` it is not a float value.

Comment: the function: `strtod()` works with `doubles` not `floats`  suggest using: `strtof()`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to manually process decimal values almost the same you process integers, but in C it would be simpler to directly iterate a number in a single pass:

```
while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) != NULL) {
    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) {
        if (isdigit(str[i])) {
            data = str[i++] - '0'; // initialize data with first digit
            while(isdigit(str[i])) {
                data = data * 10 + (str[i++] - '0');  // increment with other digits
            }
            if (str[i] == '.') { // decimal part
                double mult = .1;
                i++;
                while(isdigit(str[i])) {
                    data = data + mult * (str[i++] - '0'); // increment with decimal part
                    mult *= .1;
                }
            }
            push(data);
        }
        ...
```

But in fact `strtod` does it for you...:

```
while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) != NULL) {
    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) {
        if (isdigit(str[i])) {
            char *end;
            data = ::strtod(str+i, &end);
            i = end - str;  // that's all we are past the number...
            push(data);
        }
        ...
```